# Golang and PostgreSQL general function to add to database

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm quite new to Golang and am attempting to create a generic function allowing me to add entries to any given table in the database. I'm able to make these functions when applied to specific tables but not being able to generalise it.

Currently, I have:

Specific table, CreateUser
`

```
func CreateUser(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.DB.Db
    user := new(model.User)

    err := c.BodyParser(user)
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "error",
                                            "message": "Invalid input",
                                            "data": "err"})
    }

    err = db.Create(&user).Error
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "error",
                                            "message": "Could not create user",
                                            "data": "err"})
    }

    return c.Status(201).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "success",
                                        "message": "User created",
                                        "data": user})
}
```

My attempt to generalise this to be able to apply to any table in the DB is below:

```
func CreateEntry(c *fiber.Ctx, table interface{}) error {
    db := database.DB.Db
    entryType := reflect.TypeOf(table)
    entry := reflect.New(entryType)

    err := c.BodyParser(entry)
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "error",
                                            "message": "Invalid input",
                                            "data": "err"})
    }

    err = db.Create(&entry).Error
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(500).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "error",
                                            "message": "Could not create entry",
                                            "data": "err"})
    }

    return c.Status(201).JSON(fiber.Map{"status": "success",
                                        "message": "Entry added created",
                                        "data": entry})

}
```

Any help would be welcome, thanks

--
EDIT:
for info, database.DB.Db refers to this:

```html
package database

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

// Database instance
type Dbinstance struct {
    Db *gorm.DB
}

var DB Dbinstance
```

Comment: What package do you use for PostgreSQL? What is `database.DB.Db`?

Comment: database.DB.Db is a variable in my own database package. I'm using gorm

package database

import (
 "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
 "gorm.io/gorm"
 "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

// Database instance
type Dbinstance struct {
 Db *gorm.DB
}

var DB Dbinstance

Comment: You should change the title probably. It has nothing to do with postgresql. It's all about gorm